# changing format of date shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to change date format of last reboot time.  How can I do this? Any idea ?
I cut the other things from last reboot command. The last seems :

```
Output :  1 Nov 2015
```

But I want like this :

```
dd/mm/yyyy : 01/11/2015
```

Comment: from which command you are getting date ?

Comment: using "last -F reboot" @AmeyJadiye

Answer (score 1):

Since you already cut the output you just have to convert it to different format, try below you will find your expected format.

```
export DATE="1 Nov 2015"
date -d"$DATE" +%d/%m/%Y
01/11/2015
```

Comment: I have been done this. But I want to ask is tehere a way change format of last reboot time's format ? a=$(last -F reboot etc... ) --->this is my command and then I print "a". but the date is not a good way for me

Comment: nops, there is no option given by `last` to change date format, one thing you can do is to change the code of `last` pkg, recompile and install patch to your OS, but this is very long process :D